# How to represent Fermat number $F_n$ as a sum of three squares?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$  be  the Fermat number. How to represent the Fermat number  $F_n$ for $n \geq 3$  as a sum of three squares  of different natural numbers? For example  for   $n=3$  we have
$$
F_3=257=5^2+6^2+14^2.
$$
Is there any simple procedure  to write out such representations for another $n$?

Comment: $$F_n= (2^{2^{n-1}})^2+1^2 +0^2$$

Comment: I am sorry, the numbers must be natural and different. Zero is not allowed. I  have edited the question.

Comment: Does this question have some motivation behind it? Is it from a competition? Or just a general curiosity?

Comment: Another trivial case is $x=y=2^{2^{n-2}},z=2^{2^{n-1}}-1$...  Obviously violates the "distinct numbers" rule.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $X=2^{2^{n-1}}$. Then $X$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$, so

$$
F_n=X^2+1=\bigg(\frac{2X+1}{3}\bigg)^2+
\bigg(\frac{2X-2}{3}\bigg)^2+
\bigg(\frac{X+2}{3}\bigg)^2
$$

The values are all distinct, except when $X=1$ or $4$ (which are excluded since
$n\geq 3$).